# Cross Thread problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, batch-file

I got this code (lg_log is a listbox, and i want it to log the start_server.bat) Here is the code i got:

```
public void bt_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lg_log.Items.Add("Starting Mineme server ..");

    string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();


    var info = new ProcessStartInfo(directory + @"\start_base.bat") {UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true, CreateNoWindow = true, WorkingDirectory = directory + @"\Servers\Base"};
    var proc = new Process { StartInfo = info, EnableRaisingEvents = true };

    proc.OutputDataReceived += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Data != null)
        {
            lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data);
        }
    };
    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    lg_log.Items.Add("Server is now running!");
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

When i run this, I'll get an error ..

Edit: The error i get is this: System.InvalidOperationException Hope it helps :)

The error comes at the lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data); code line

Comment: Could you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: the full exception, please. Saying "InvalidOperationException" is useless information.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if (args.Data != null)
{
    lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data);
}
```

with

```
if (args.Data != null)
{
    if (lg_log.InvokeRequired)
        lg_log.Invoke(new Action(() => lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data)));
    else
        lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I'll get an error at the new Action(() code .. Maybe i need to write a Using system.Something?

Comment: @Frederik You don't need a new Action, () => lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data) should be enough.

Comment: Unless you are using 2.0 :-) :-)

Comment: @Frederik, It is in the System namespace, but introduced in .NET 3 or 4 or something like that. You can declare it yourself `public delegate void Action();`

Comment: Thank you very much guys! My problem is now solved thank you!

Comment: But the worst thing is that i can't vote up - I need 15 reputation :(

Comment: @Frederik You should not do `proc.WaitForExit();` in the button click event since that will block your UI thread

Answer (score 0):

```
lg_log.Items.Add(args.Data);
```

This line might get executed on a different thread than the UI thread. Use this.BeginInvoke(...) to update the UI on the UI Thread.

To verify the execution on a non-UI htread note that the message of the InvalidOperation will state Cross-thread access to the UI

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(UpdateUI(args.Data));
....

private void UpdateUI(string data)
{
    lg_log.Items.Add(data);
}
```