# C# - Live read a batch file in a (rich)textbox

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-line

In my Windows Forms program, I want to read a batch file in live. After searching, I found the way to do it. But it only works in a console. If I replace the console.writefile with a richtextbox.appendtext etc, it says "InvalidOperationException".

Here is my code

```
var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Rayan\Desktop",
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments =  "/c test.bat",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,                  
                UseShellExecute = false           
            }
        };

        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => { richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data + "\n"); };
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

I tested many things but nothing works. Thanks for you help,
Polymeth.

Comment: OutputDataReceived is raised on a separate thread from the UI you need to  make a thread safe call to the control.  Here is a question almost identical to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051550/cross-thread-problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Thread problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051550/cross-thread-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because u accessing a UI-Control (richTextBox1) in a different thread.
UI-Controls can only be accessed in the UI thread. But u can Invoke the access. I don't tested it myself but i think it should prevent the InvalidOperationException.

```
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => { 
    richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(delegate() {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data + "\n");
    });
};
```